# Authentication for in-browser client-side APIs?

Tags: authentication, client

I'm thinking of the Google Static Maps API, which limits you to 1000 static maps, more if you sign up for an account. How do they keep track of accounts and such, when everything on the client is public?

For most server-to-server APIs I am given a access_token/key/etc. which I can pass to the service to prove that I am indeed me, but on the client any such access_token/key/etc. would immediately become public knowledge.

In general, what strategies to client side libraries (FB SDK, Stripe, Google, etc) use to perform authentication, and how do they get around the fact that everything on the client is public?

Comment: With Google Static Maps, one still needs to request the map image from Google's servers, therefore usage can be detected at that time; they probably use the HTTP referer information sent by the client to assign each request to an account.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I suppose my question then is: How does Google know that it's actually a page on my site requesting the image? What stops someone from copying the URL from one of my pages, changing the parameters and using it all over own site, using up my quota in the process?

Comment: The user's browser includes in the header information of its request to Google the address of the referring page... whilst the user themselves could manipulate that to misreport someone else's site (to what end?), it's not something that another site would be able to do in the manner you describe.

Comment: @eggyal could you elaborate on that? I have no idea how the referrer header information works, or how I can get/use it as a server or using S3/cloudfront. A link I could go to learn up on this would be awesome too =)

Comment: When a browser requests a resource from a webserver it includes in the "[request headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html)" the URL of the referring page.  Therefore, the server can determine (for example) on which page an image it is serving is embedded (provided that the browser has not been manipulated to misreport this information).  How you read this will depend on the server-side technologies in use: in PHP, for example, one could just inspect [`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your API key to whitelist [by host](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#whitelistingbyhost) which tells Google Maps to only allow the API key to be used from a site sending a referrer that matches your whitelist.

If some other site uses your API key, they'll get this error message on load:

> This web site needs a different Google Maps API key. A new key can be generated at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/introduction.html#Obtaining_Key.

You can verify this yourself by using the [RefControl extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/refcontrol/) for FireFox:

- Using the extension, Override your referrer to, say, http://www.microsoft.com/
- Access an example site for google maps that's not hosted by google - e.g., http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_controlpos.htm
- You should get the error.

This works because:

- Practically all web browsers send a referrer [(i.e., the URI of the resource which links to it)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) as part of a request.
- For someone to steal your API key (since as you say, it's a publicly available string), they would need to tell all their users to override their referrers to match the site they stole it from (which clearly isn't practical).

Note that Google seem to allow requests that contain no referrer - I guess the amount of browsers that are configured to exclude this information is minuscule and therefore not worth caring about.